# Angular 13 - Circular dependency when using overlay.attach (service imports a component that imports the service)

Tags: angular

### Code and structure

- NotificationModule

  - ContainerComponent
  - NotificationComponent
- NotificationService

NotificationService is in charge of the overlay initialization and to hold the data used to show notifications.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class NotificationService {
  public queue: NotificationConfig[] = [];
  private overlayRef!: OverlayRef;
  constructor(private overlay: Overlay) {
    this.createOverlay();
  }

  private createOverlay(): void {
    const overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
      positionStrategy: this.overlay.position().global().bottom().right(),
    });
    overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(NotificationContainerComponent));
  }
}
```

ContainerComponent uses NotificationService (it has an *ngFor that depends on the queue property).

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-container",
  templateUrl: "./container.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./container.component.scss"],
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  constructor(public notificationSrv: NotificationService) {}
}
```

### The problem

Whenever I inject NotificationService on any other component's constructor it will trigger a circular dependency.

### What I tried

1. Using a ContainerWrapperComponent and attaching the overlay to that one, ContainerWrapperComponent's html shows ContainerComponent. Didn't work, same error.
2. Using an OverlayService and calling that service from NotificationService passing NotificationContainerComponent as parameter. Didn't work, same error.

I can move the overlay.create and attach to the app.component and this would be solved but I don't like that workaround. The overlay creation and the attachment should happen only if a component uses the notificationService (that's why it is inside the notificationService), and only the notificationService should have the logic to do this.

Comment: ContainerComponent is a container for the notifications, that's why it belong in the Notification Module. Also removing it from that module wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. The ContainerComponent is used as a view container for NotificationComponent. They are both part of the NotificationModule. ContainerComponent uses NotificationService (as shown in the question)

Comment: No, those other components do not extend the ContainerComponent. They are normal components importing NotificationService. When you inject NotificationService for the first time it will instantiate the service.